# Override struct tags in go

Tags: json, go, struct, dry

I have an entity in my project that is viewable by public and by admin. Not all fields should be accessible by public.

For example

```
type Foo struct {
    Id        bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    DateAdded time.Time     `json:"date_added" bson:"date_added"`
    Bar       string `json:"bar" bson:"bar"`      
    AdminOnly string        `json:"admin_only" bson:"admin_only"`
}
```

AdminOnly field should be only visible to admins.
For now, when requests comes from public, I call separate method that copies every needed field to new struct

```
type FooPublic struct {
    Id        bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    DateAdded time.Time     `json:"date_added" bson:"date_added"`
    Bar       string `json:"bar" bson:"bar"`
}

func (f *Foo) Public() (res FooPublic) {
    res = FooPublic{
        Id: f.Id,
        DateAdded: f.DateAdded,
        Bar:f.Bar,
    }
    return
}
```

But if I need to add new field to my entity, I need to add it in 3 places. In struct itself, in `PublicFoo` and in `Public` method.
This seems to be agains DRY principle. What is correct, idiomatic solution here? Can I define `FooPublic` so it overrides tags of needed fields? Or probably there is at least good way to copy corresponding fields from one struct to another, so I don't need to do this manually in `Public` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general this repetition can be avoided by using [embedding](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types). Your `Foo` type should embed `FooPublic`:

```
type FooPublic struct {
    Id        bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    DateAdded time.Time     `json:"date_added" bson:"date_added"`
    Bar       string        `json:"bar" bson:"bar"`      
}

type Foo struct {
    FooPublic
    AdminOnly string `json:"admin_only" bson:"admin_only"`
}

func (f *Foo) Public() FooPublic {
    return f.FooPublic
}
```

But if someone is able to call the `Foo.Public()`, that someone already has the `Foo` or `*Foo` value (and so can access the exported `AdminOnly` field), so what's the point?

A better solution would be to use an interface, and not expose the `Foo` struct.

Comment: Thanks. That seem to be working solution for me. 
When I said about public and admin access, I meant roles of my app users, so depending on user role I either return Foo or FooPublic as json.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need that `Public()` method at all. If you have `type Foo struct { FooPublic; AdminOnly string; }` then you can get at the embedded `FooPublic` value of `var foo Foo` with `foo.FooPublic`.